# Blockquote button in edit panel creates strange output

Tags: bug

On Chromium, pressing the blockquote button in the edit panel toolbar gives the following:

```
Blockquote

Blockquote> BlockquoteBlockquote

Blockquote
```

Similar results if some text is highlighted beforehand.

Comment: Somehow i missed the same problem on the mothership (and the closed meta post there as well).

Comment: This was [posted on meta again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63307/blockquote-glitch-in-editor-in-chrome-6) yesterday, so I'm going to close it here